# Fourier transform $\frac1{t^2+2t+2}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I need help to calculate the Fourier transform of this function:

$$\frac1{t^2+2t+2}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: For example, have you tried completing the square?

Comment: I have no idea how to start with it?

Comment: Do you know the Fourier transform of $1/(t^2+1)$?  Do you know how Fourier transform of $f(t)$ and $f(t+c)$ are related?

Comment: Yes! If I take f(t)=1/(t^2+1) => f(t+1)=1/(1+(1+t)^2)=1/(t^2+2t+2) which is my function and then I can use that f(t+c)=e^(-icw)*F(w) because I know the transform of 1/(t^2+1)?

Answer (score 2):

We know that

$$\mathcal{F}(e^{-a|x|})=\frac{2a}{w^2+a^2}$$

Therefore

$$\frac{2a}{x^2+a^2}\overset{\mathcal{F}}{\longrightarrow}2\pi e^{-a|w|}$$

Also

$$f(x-a) \overset{\mathcal{F}}{\longrightarrow} e^{-iaw}\mathcal{F(w)}$$

From the last formula  and $a=1$ we have that

$$\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{t^2+2t+2}\right)=\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{(t+1)^2+1}\right)=e^{iaw}\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{t^2+1}\right)=(e^{iaw})(\pi e^{-|w|})$$

Comment: Note that should be an $1$ instead of an $a$ in the last formulas.

Comment: yes. i want recommend general formula